# Является ли правильным употребление слова "качественно"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Является ли правильным употребление слова "качественно"? Ведь по сути оно ничего не выражает: качество может быть как плохим, так и хорошим.

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю ваших проблем.
Да, качество может быть плохим и хорошим. Почему на этом основании надо отказываться от слова "качественно" в значении, например, "хорошо"? Кстати, есть ведь и антоним - некачественно?

Comment: Не согласен. А "некачественно" звучит ещё отвратительнее...

Comment: Тогда не со мной надо спорить, а со словарями. У Ефремвой, например, это значение прописано явно. Причем в обоиз вариантах - и как наречие и ка предикатив.  

Качественно  
....  
2.   
Отличаясь высокой степенью ценности, пригодности, соответствия тому, каким следует быть.  
....  
2.   
Оценочная характеристика чего-либо как отличающегося высокой степенью ценности, пригодности, соответствия тому, каким следует быть  
  
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/174151/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE

Answer (score 0):

Качества могут быть те или не те, нужными или неуместными. А их уровень бывает неприемлемым или сносным, посредственным, невысоким, низким или предельным-запредельным. У оценки «***качественно***» свой уровень. Она кратко, но понятно говорит о состоянии качества значением выше среднего, то есть не вызывающего вопросы или претензии.

Сомнение в правильности употребления тогда возникает, когда это слово покидает среду «техно». Там, где уместны такие слова, как *тонко*, *артистично*, *изящно*, давать оценку «качественно» неприлично, ну разве только с долей уместной иронии.